# Wikipedia Database 'pagelinks' "What links here" SQL query

Tags: sql, wikipedia

I'm trying to search e.g. for all articles, linking to a special wikipedia article. E.g. how many articles point to "Carsharing". On the "real" Wiki pages, I can do this by clicking "What links here", found in the "toolbox" category. The time needed for this request is low.

But when I try to do this kind of query programmatically on my local installed Wiki database by searching the "page links" table e.g. by doing this `` SELECT *  FROM `pagelinks` WHERE `pl_title` = 'Carsharing' ``, it needs at least 1 minute (on a really fast local system).

Is there any way to do get the results as fast as on the "real" Wiki pages?

Comment: Do you have a local datadump of wikipedia or on what data do you execute this query? are you aware of the fact that "a really fast local system" is most likely still slower than the high-end data servers used for websites like wikipedia? Furthermore, those queries most likely are cached someway or another.

Comment: Yes, a local install of the complete wikipedia dump (including the 'pagelinks' table in a MySQL database). Thanks

Comment: …and don't forget the `LIMIT 50` MediaWiki is using on the backlinks page by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an index on the pl_title column (if not present) can significantly improve the preformance of your query, changing a O(n) lookup to a O(log(n)) lookup.

Comment: Works perfect for me :-) Now the query time is at about 0,021 sec. Thanks again :-)